# ImportError: No module named watchdog.observers

Tags: python-3.x, macos, watchdog

I am stuck with this issue

> ImportError: No module named watchdog.observers

I have done pip install and whatever I can find.
I am running on macOS --version Catalina.

Please help if you have any suggestions how to solve this.

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0):

1. Try importing a specific class/function:

   `from watchdog.observers import Observer`
2. Try installing watchdog with root-privileges for your version of python:

   `sudo pip install watchdog`

   *or*

   `sudo pip2 install watchdog`

   *or*

   `sudo pip3 install watchdog`

Seeing your code would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer but it didn't work for me. See below cut from my code:
"from watchdog.observers import Observer
import time
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import os
import json
import shutil
from datetime import datetime
from time import gmtime, strftime

class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        for filename in os.listdir(folder_to_track):
            i = 1
            if filename != 'jonas':

Comment: See below from Terminal:
Requirement already satisfied: watchdog in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=3.10 in atchdog) (0.26.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pathtools>=0.1.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from watchdog) (0.1.2)
Jonass-MBP:Scripts JL$ python cleandesk.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cleandesk.py", line 1, in <module>
    from watchdog.observers import Observer
ImportError: No module named watchdog.observers

Comment: Have you installed watchdog for the correct python version? Please paste the output of these two commands here: `python --version` and `pip --version`

Comment: Ah so I have wrong version...
Jonass-MBP:~ JL$ python --version
Python 2.7.16
Jonass-MBP:~ JL$ pip --version
pip 19.2.3 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
Jonass-MBP:~ JL$ 
How do I change that? I have downloaded python3 with homebrew. Do I need to change the path somehow?

Comment: Now it worked with python3 but I get this error instead: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/JL/Desktop/Relocated Items/Configuration/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default'
Tried to remove the permission but I still fail.

Comment: Try and see if your /Python2.7/Scripts folder has the pip-executable. If it does, try installing watchdog with the full pip path ex. `C:/Python2.7/Scripts/pip2.7.exe install watchdog` or try installing watchdog for Python3 with `pip3 install watchdog`